# Maximal number of colours in a palette that allows for fewer than 500 mixtures

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, logarithms, arithmetic

An artist is planning on mixing together any number of different colours from her palette. A mixture results as long as the artist combines at least two colours. If the number of possible mixtures is less than 500, what is the greatest number of colours the artist could have in her palette?

Comment: Hint: The number of subsets is $2^n$ so the number of mixtures is $2^n-n-1$. Now experiment.

Comment: how is this problem related to logarithms: I would think combinatorics is a more appropriate tag? I assume that  different mixtures result from mixing different combinations of colors, and that the same mixture results when you mix the same set of colors, regardless of how much exactly you put in the mix from each individual color? Well, I could see how logarithms might be related, you are looking at subsets, so log base 2 is related.

Comment: @user48481 Probably a section on logarithms in some discrete mathematics book, since the problem involves solving for $n$ in $2^n$.

Comment: It's not clear what difficulty you have with this exercise. (See: [How to ask a Good Question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959))

Answer (score 3):

Assume that the artist has $n$ colours. Then the possible number of mixtures with

- $2$ colours, is equal to $\dbinom{n}{2}$
- $3$ colours, is equal to $\dbinom{n}{3}$,
- $\ldots$,
- $n-1$ colours, is equal to $\dbinom{n}{n-1}$,
- $n$ colours, is equal to $\dbinom{n}{n}$,

Thus the total number of mixtures is equal to $$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=-\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}1^{n-k}1^k=-1-n+(1+1)^n$$ by the Binomial Theorem. Thus you need to find the maximum $n$ that satisfies $$-1-n+2^n<500 \iff 2^n-n<501$$ By trial and error and since the LHS is increasing in $n$, you can find that $$2^8-8=248<501 \\ 2^9-9=503\not<501$$ therefore the maximum such $n$ is $n=8$.

---

As indicated in the comments, a more straightforward way to calculate the total number of mixtures is to observe that if you have $n$ colours then there are $2^n$ possible sets of colours ($2^n$ is the cardinality of the powerset). Now from this $2^n$ sets exclude all sets that contain just 1 colour (there are $n$ such sets) and the empty set. Thus, you obtain that there are $$2^n-n-1$$ possible mixtures.